# Is there a way to easily convert a flat DataTable to a nested .NET object?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I have a large hand tuned SQL query that returns a flat data table with many (>25) columns.

Currently, I manually convert that to a .NET object with three levels of nesting (i.e. an object which contains (among other properties) a list of further objects which contains (among other properties) a list of further objects.

Is there anything with the ease of something like AutoMapper which can convert a DataTable into a target .NET object, even if its nested?

Comment: Have you considered LINQ-TO-SQL?

Comment: @PhillyNJ Yes, but this is not suitable in this situation. I need this to be an ultra fast query, so a hand optimized SQL query is what I have to start with. This is proving to be at least an order of magnitude faster than Entity Framework. Due to political reasons, I cant slot in another heavyweight ORM framework, so I have to do this particular series of queries manually.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788242/how-do-i-use-automapper-to-map-a-dataset-with-multiple-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the original poster of this question.

It turns out that I was asking the wrong question: I should have been asking how to easily perform fast queries which map into a complex arrangement of POCOs.

I have posted the solution that worked perfectly for me, see [How do I write one to many query in Dapper.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350467/how-do-i-write-one-to-many-query-in-dapper-net/30080951#30080951) and the answer that references Dapper + Slapper.Automapper.