# C# Data Access Layer (Not EF but SP and objects)

Tags: c#, data-layer

I have ben requested to create an application that uses an existing DB with stored procedures (`insert`, `update`, `delete`) and they **don't want** to use `Entity Framework`.

One way is to create my own **Data Access Layer** using `System.Data.DataSet` but I would like to know if there is any existing library or something I can use where I can fill objects from SP's and also update data using SP's.

> Any clue?

Comment: Check [Dapper.NET](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#stored-procedures)

Comment: Yes, Entity Framework. You can use stored procedures with EF. Usually though developers are given a task but not told they can't use specific tools that lend themselves nicely to the job. Why the requirement not to use EF?

Comment: Performance in EF is horrible with big datasets.

Comment: Drapper sounds a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a micro-orm like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#stored-procedures) which is simple, efficient and maps correctly to objects.

Example of use :

```
// Call spGetUser with a parameter Id and put the result in a User instance.  
var user = cnn.Query<User>("spGetUser", new {Id = 1}, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Does Dapper can track of changes over the entity? So I can know what property was changed, etc.?

Comment: @VAAA You can use [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib) to do it.

Comment: Amazing!! thats what Im looking

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go down this path, you can use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)

Take a look at this post
[How do I use automapper to map a dataset with multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788242/how-do-i-use-automapper-to-map-a-dataset-with-multiple-tables)

Still, keep in mind that performance can actually be really bad.

IMHO, EF would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I usually recommend to use Dapper. it is very light-weight, it's performance is on par with ADO.NET coding.

Comment: Does Dapper can track of changes over the entity? So I can know what property was changed, etc.?

Comment: No, it is just direct query and execute operations, extending the connection object.